# Defining margin-top in react in VH

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, javascript-objects

I want to define the height of this container with VH but when i do i get errors.

```
  return (
<Container style={{ marginTop: 80vh }}>
  <Container maxWidth="xs" style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    <Paper
      style={{
        padding: 24,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#151A1F',
        borderRadius: 6,
      }}
    >
```

Comment: It should be a string {{marginTop: '80vh'}}

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a string:

```js
<Container style={{ marginTop: "80vh" }}>
```